# Import TFS OnPrem into Existing Organization Account

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

Is it possible to import an on-prem TFS instance into an existing organization account on Azure DevOps?

If not - can you move projects to different organization accounts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On how to import an on-premises TFS instance into azure devops , you could try to use the [Migration Guide](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/devops/migrate/) to progress through your import. This guide links to the technical documentation, as needed.

Here is a [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/migrate/migration-import?view=azure-devops) walks through how to perform all of the necessary preparation work required to get an import to Azure DevOps Services ready to run. Notes about importing on-premises TFS instance into azure devops are also indicated in this document.
  If you encounter errors during the process ,you could also review the [troubleshooting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/migrate/migration-troubleshooting?view=azure-devops).